# jQuery Validation Plugin error placement on same line as input box

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I'm trying to display the validation error messages on the same line as the input.

For example:
SITE NAME: |input box | This field is required (error displayed by jQuery plugin)

Below is a fiddle of my html structure and jQuery code. Can someone help, please?
https://jsfiddle.net/ebyoqmgs/

```
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo( element.parent("div").next() );   }
```

It's still looking like this. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image: Errrors displayed on a new line]

Comment: It would really help if you took the time to properly construct the jsFiddle.  You failed to include jQuery and the plugin.

Comment: Your code is already doing exactly what you want:  http://jsfiddle.net/h32rb63g/

Comment: The errors are still displayed on the next line. I'm not sure what the issue is. Been trying things for hours. I uploaded picture of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Your problem is apparently being caused by something within your HTML structure, not your JavaScript or this plugin.  You'll have to inspect your DOM and troubleshoot it.  Otherwise, I've already shown you that the code you've posted is working as requested:  http://jsfiddle.net/h32rb63g/

Comment: Please do not open new SO accounts for the purpose of asking the same question multiple times. http://stackoverflow.com/q/34733230/594235

Answer (score 0):

javascript

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
   $("#new-site-form").validate({
     rules: {
       siteName: "required",
       contactName: "required",
       contactNumber: {
         required: true,
         //email: true //replace with phone validation
       },
       contactEmail: {
        required: true,
        email: true
       },
       address1: {
        required: true,
       },
       city: "required",
       state: "required",
       zipCode: "required",
       //survey-date: "required",
       frpmAmount: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
       },   
    },

     errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.appendTo( element.parent("div").next() );
    }
   });
 });
 </script>
```

HTML Code

```
 <div class="body-container">
  <form id="new-site-form" method="post" action="">
   <div>
      <label for="siteName">Site Name *</label>
      <input id="siteName" name="siteName" type="text">
   </div>
   <div>
      <label for="contactName">On-site Contact Name *</label>
      <input id="contactName" name="contactName" type="text">
   </div>  
   <div>
      <label for="contactNumber">Contact Number *</label>
       <input id="contactNumber" name="contactNumber" type="text" 
       placeholder="(555)-555-5555">
   </div>
   <div>
     <label for="contactEmail">Contact Email *</label>
     <input id="contactEmail" name="contactEmail" type="email">
   </div>
   <div>
     <label for="address1">Address 1 *</label>
     <input id="address1" name="address1" type="text">
   </div>
   <div>
     <label for="address2">Address 2</label>
     <input id="address2" name="address2" type="text">
   </div>
   <div>
     <label for="city-state">City * / State *</label>
     <input id="city" name="city" type="text">
    <div class="select-style">
      <select id="state">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div>
     <label for="zipCode">Zip code *</label>
     <input id="zipCode" name="zipCode" type="text">
   </div>
    <div>
      <label for="surveyDate">Survey Date *</label>
      <input id="surveyDate" name="surveyDate" type="date">
    </div>
    <div>
     <label for="frpmAmount">FRPM Amount (%) *</label>
     <input id="frpmAmount" name="frpmAmount" type="number">
    </div>
    <div class="radio-container">
     <div class="float-left">
      <label for="during-or-after">During or After Office Hours *</label>
      <input type="radio" name="during-or-after" value="during" checked>During
      <input class="radio-with-left-margin" type="radio" name="during-or-after" value="after">After
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="radio-container">
      <div class="float-left">
        <label for="keys-issued">Can Access Keys be Issued to Crew Supervisor? *</label>
         <input type="radio" name="keys-issued" value="yes" checked>Yes
         <input class="radio-with-left-margin" type="radio" name="keys-issued" value="no">No
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
      <div>
        <label for="site-building-map">Site and Building Map File Upload</label>
        <input id="site-building-map" name="site-building-map" type="file">
      </div>
      <div id="submit-buttons">
        <a href="sites-list.html"><input class="button-with-right-margin"
                                 type="button" value="Cancel" /></a>
         <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
        </div>
      </form>
  </div>
```

Style Sheet

```
.select-style{
   display: inline-table;
   padding: 0;
   margin-bottom:6px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   width: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #fff;
   background: #fff url("images/arrowdown.gif") no-repeat 90% 50%;
}

.select-style select{
  padding: 5px 8px;
  width: 130%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.select-style select:focus{
  outline: none;
}
.error { color:red; }
```